# "using namespace std;" before "#include <foo>"

Tags: c++, c++11

What are the differences in compilability or generated code (if any) between the following two source files:

**Exhibit A**:

```
namespace std {};
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <string>

<any code here>
```

**Exhibit B**:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

<any code here>
```

Assuming the two `<any code here>` placeholders are replaced with any identical user code.

Put another way: Is there any user visible difference if "using namespace std;" is put before the standard `#includes` (assuming namespace std has been introduced as above)?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you asked this.

Comment: First off, "Exhibit A" is illegal in C++: you are not allowed to re-open the `std` namespace.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Do you have a standard reference for that?

Comment: @user1131467: Unfortunately not.  I remember getting that from "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup, but I can't find a suitable reference at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As unlikely as it may be, the following code could possibly be in your implementation's vector header:

```
namespace __AA
{
    class vector {};
}

namespace std
{
    // actual std::vector implementation here
}

namespace __BB
{
    using namespace __AA;
    vector x;
}
```

Now with **Exhibit A**, you've got an ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

In any practical standard library implementation there will be no difference whatsoever, since the using directive will have no impact on definitions inside of namespace `std` (as `std` is already the current scope).

If any standard library implementation *were* negatively affected either way, I would consider it a *serious* quality-of-implementation defect.